# home servers and wireless router

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking

I have 4 servers at home that I use for hosting several websites, mail, database. Lately traffic has been increased more than double in the last couple weeks from 2K unique visitors to about 4K unique visitors per week (125K hits/week - avg 5-10KB/hit cached ). The internet connection is a 10Mbps/1Mbps. All servers are connected to a home DLink wireless router that works as a firewall. The problem is that sometimes I do have to reboot BOTH, my ISP modem and the wireless router because connection just goes off.

My question is, it is the wireless router that is getting saturated? if so, which router should I replace it with?

Any suggestions will be appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You really should be connecting those servers to the switch with a wire...

Wireless is nowhere near reliable enough for server application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain your ISP isn't turning your service off for TOS violations?  :)

My modem (running of cable) can handle a sustained incoming flow of nearly 18 Mbps, and outgoing of around 5 Mbps.  I don't have any problems with my cable modem, but my firewall machine is a NetBSD box.

If I had to place money on what is broken, I'd have to know what type the modem is, but I'd point a finger at the d-link box nearly immediately.  I have yet to see a home-grade wireless router handle any real traffic.

Comment: I dont think is a TOS violation, is a business account. Router DLINK WBR-1310

Comment: Good news then.  If you have to reboot both though, something is certainly wrong.  Can you call your ISP when it craps out, and ask them if they can ping the modem from the cable-side?  Can you ping it?  It's probably 192.168.100.1, but of course if your wireless router is locked, you might be unable to...

Answer (score 0):

Home routers are notoriously flakey and restarting them is a pretty common task.  I've had many cheap D-link / Netgear / etc routers and they all lock up often...and eventually just die.  The modem from your ISP may be to blame as well...but there's not as much you can do about that.

If you want to stick with home-grade equipment, the Linksys [WRT54G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series) is well known for being reliable.  I have one myself, and it rarely needs to be restarted.

If you want to step up a notch, look into small-business grade routers like the Linksys [RV042](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9925/index.html), which will run somewhere around $200.  I've had one running non stop with constant traffic for over a year I think.  Now this unit doesn't have wireless built in, but if you're only using wireless for the client machines in your house, then you could put your existing wireless router behind the RV042.